# How use send_keystrokes in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Please specify the module/library that needs to be imported to use send_keystrokes in pywinauto. If possible please attach any snippet of example code that you have performed using the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use type_keys() - refer here for more details - https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html

Some PyWinAuto Examples on Git - https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/master/examples

Comment: type_keys() or send_keys() work only when the screen is active and not locked. I want to run send_keys() in a scheduling process using pywinauto in a Remote Desktop (when the system is locked). When I tried running with send_keys() it doesn't happen. Is there any way around for this?

Comment: As far as I know PyWinAuto, it does not works on locked pc...

Comment: Some methods may work on a locked PC, but it's really a hard quest. I would recommend to try different recipes with Remote Desktop configuring or using VNC: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).